# How to draw custom elements with python?

Tags: python, interface

How to draw custom faces/lines/points in 3D space with python?

Like [this addon](http://cgcookie.com/blender/2014/10/09/retopology-tool-polystrips-released/).

I need just a simple example of how to draw these elements.

Comment: Take a look at the Github page: https://github.com/CGCookie/retopology-contours/blob/master/contour_classes.py

Comment: Possibly off topic because involves external addon?

Comment: @VinceScalia I think the OP mentioned the addon as an example of functionality, not because they were asking how to use it. IMO it's a perfectly good question.

Comment: Okay then. Just wondering.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Blender provides opengl access through python with the [bgl module](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_72_1/bgl.html) which allows you to use opengl calls to draw to screen. Any opengl reference should help.

An example from the [contours addon - countour_utilities.py](https://github.com/CGCookie/retopology-contours/blob/master/contour_utilities.py)

```
def draw_outline_or_region(mode, points, color):
        '''  
        arg: 
        mode - either bgl.GL_POLYGON or bgl.GL_LINE_LOOP
        color - will need to be set beforehand using theme colors. eg
        bgl.glColor4f(self.ri, self.gi, self.bi, self.ai)
        '''

        bgl.glColor4f(color[0],color[1],color[2],color[3])
        if mode == 'GL_LINE_LOOP':
            bgl.glBegin(bgl.GL_LINE_LOOP)
        else:
            bgl.glBegin(bgl.GL_POLYGON)

        # start with corner right-bottom
        for i in range(0,len(points)):
            bgl.glVertex2f(points[i][0],points[i][1])

        bgl.glEnd()
```